# Openness of a subset in complex 2-plane

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, several-complex-variables

Let   $U$ be a subset of $\mathbb{C}^{2}$ containing the origin $0$.  Assume that for  any curve $C$ (an affine variety of dimension 1, maybe singular) passing through $0$ we have $U \cap C$ is Zariski open in $C$. Is $U$  Zariski open in $\mathbb{C}^{2}$? Or at least, is there a Zariski neighborhood $V$ of $0$ with $V\subset U$?  Thanks!

Comment: When you say that $C$ is an affine variety of dimension $1$, does your definition of a variety include that $C$ is irreducible?

Comment: No, C can be reducible.

Comment: Okay, thanks for clarifying. I asked because $U$ need not be open if we restrict ourselves to *irreducible* curves passing through $0$, but I'm not sure in general. Notice that if we allow reducible curves, the $C \cap U$ open in $U$ for $C$ containing $0$ implies that the intersection of *any* curve with $U$ is open in the curve (that is, even for curves not containing $0$), since we can realize any curve as a union of components of a curve passing through $0$.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I also like to know what happens if we insist C is irreducible. Any counterexample?  Actually, a neighborhood V of 0 in U being open is enough for me. Is it true if we insist C being irreducible?

Comment: For a counterexample to the claim that $U$ is open if we only consider $C$ irred: let $U$ be the complement of $\{(z,w):z=1\text{ and }1\leq |w|\leq 2\}$. For any irreducible curve $C$ passing through $0$, $C \cap \{(z,w):z=1\}$ is finite, since it's a Zariski closed in $C$. Hence $C \cap U^c$ is finite, and $C \cap U$ is open in $C$. But $U$ is not open, because $U^c$ is a proper infinite subset of the irreducible curve $z=1$. The problem with allowing reducible curves is that the curve $z=1$ itself has non-open intersection with $U$. I'll have to think about the open neighborhood part.